# Error : "Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined" when transforming Angular 8 to Angular Universal

Tags: angular

Just need your help regarding an error during transformation of normal Angular app into Angular Universal.
This error "Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined" keeps on ringing everytime I run this ng command "ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject my-project-name. What do I need to change to remove this error.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

What's your Angular version?

Try also update angular dev kit

`npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular`

Comment: Hi Marcin, I'm using Angular CLI: 8.3.29

Comment: Hi Marcin, I have new error after updating my @angular-devkit/build-angular, "An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@schematics/angular/utility/json-file'

Comment: Please try `npm uninstall @schematics/angular npm cache clean npm install @schematics/angular@8.3.29` After that `npm i @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.803.17`

Comment: Error still the same after uninstalling and installing, "An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@schematics/angular/utility/json-file'